# jquery validate future date addMethod();

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-validate

Some question for jquery validate plugin and only date in future.

I've got an input field like this:

```
<input id="date_hinfahrt" class="gui-input error" type="date" required="" name="datefuture" placeholder=" DD/MM/YYYY" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
```

please, **I dont want the datepicker** in it!! There is only a mask like this:

```
 $("#datefuture").mask('99/99/9999', {placeholder:'_'});
```

And for the validate plugin I've try this addMethod(); 
but it's not working and I hope someone can help me.

```
$.validator.addMethod("minDate", function(value, element) {
    var now = new Date(); 
    var myDate = new Date(value);
    var mD = ("0" + (myDate.getDate())).slice(-2) + '/' + ("0" + (myDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();
    var nowdate = ("0" + (now.getDate())).slice(-2) + '/' + ("0" + (now.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/' + now.getFullYear();
    return this.optional(element) || mD > nowdate;
    // else alert('Das passt nicht!' + mD +  '   ' + nowdate);
});
```

Comment: I don't understand all that slicing and concatenating? Why not `myDate > now`?

Comment: Provide a plunkr or jsFiddle example, please.

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dieandere/6qprywg0/

Answer (score 9):

You can just compare dates directly, you don't need to do all that concatenation.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("minDate", function (value, element) {
    var now = new Date();
    var myDate = new Date(value);
    return this.optional(element) || myDate > now;

    // else alert('Das passt nicht!' + mD +  '   ' + nowdate);

});
```

There were also problems in the way you set up your fiddle. You had `name="date_hinfahrt"`, but in your `rules:` option you used `datefuture`. Also, `formtools.js` doesn't work with `type="date"` inputs, so it was emptying the field, causing it always to complain that the field is required; I changed it to `type="text"`.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/6qprywg0/10/)